# Laravel Query builder - select top 1 row from another table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this SQL query for MySQL which works fine. But I need to rewrite it using query builder and need to avoid `DB::raw()` completely because development database is different from production. I know far from ideal, but unfortunately it is what it is.

```
SELECT athletes.*, 
     (
         SELECT performance
         FROM performances
         WHERE athletes.id = performances.athlete_id AND performances.event_id = 1
         ORDER BY performance DESC
         LIMIT 0,1
     ) AS personal_best
FROM athletes
ORDER BY personal_best DESC
Limit 0, 100
```

And I'm struggling how to rewrite the `personal_best` part. I have table of performances for athletes and I need to select only the best performance for each athletes as his personal best.

I was trying to search for answer but all of the answers I found included raw adding raw SQL.

Any ideas or hint would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

So I accepted I might have to use Eloquent for this, but still having trouble to progress. Heres my code:

```
class Athlete extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'athletes';

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Get the performances for the Athelete post.
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function performances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EloquentModels\Performance', 'athlete_id');
    }
}

class Performance extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'performances';

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new connection at `database.php` like mysql_dev for development parameters.

```
DB::connection('mysql_dev')->table('athletes')
    ->leftJoin('performances','athletes.id','performances.athlete_id')
    ->where('performances.event_id',1)
    ->groupBy('athletes.id')
    ->orderByDesc('personal_best')
    ->select('athletes.*',DB::raw('MAX(performances.performance) AS personal_best')
    ->paginate(100);
```

try like this without raw,

```
DB::connection('mysql_dev')->table('athletes')
    ->leftJoin('performances','athletes.id','performances.athlete_id')
    ->where('performances.event_id',1)
    ->groupBy('athletes.id')
    ->orderByDesc('performances.performance')
    ->select('athletes.*','performances.performance'
    ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: @Marek Barta, if you need query builder, you can do like this. Maybe you can get an error because of database structure, but you can fix it easily.

Comment: Yes thats little bit more what I'm looking for, but is there a way to avoid the DB::raw part? Its a stupid situation I'm in right now. The database server may change over time so I would like to avoid rewritiing all the quieres if that happens

Comment: I'm getting 0 results now. Of course it might be my fault and trying to make sure I'm not making a mistake due to the database structure but it should be alright

Comment: If you said performances are wrong I could say builder is wrong. But 0 results are quite unexpected. Looks like no performance at event_id 1 but you said raw query work truly. You can change from ->paginate(100) to ->toSql() to check builder execute true SQL?

Comment: Ok that make sense. But even if that would work it wouldnt help me because if there is no performance at event_id 1 I still need that row but instead of the actual performace there would be null. Is this possible or it is getting way to complicated?

Comment: Ok my bad sorry. laravel join makes inner join. You need left join so change it with ->join to ->leftjoin or ->leftJoin it will work.

Comment: It took me roughtly forever, but I finally made it work based on your answer! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using raw SQL just do `MAX` for performance for each athlete using `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT athletes.*, MAX(performance) AS personal_best
FROM athletes
INNER JOIN performances ON athletes.id = performances.athlete_id AND performances.event_id = 1
GROUP BY athletes.id
ORDER BY personal_best DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Laravel Query Builder:

```
DB::table('athletes')
    ->join('performances', 'athletes.id', '=', 'performances.athlete_id')
    ->where('performances.event_id', '=', 1)
    ->groupBy('athletes.id')
    ->orderBy('personal_best', 'desc')
    ->select('athletes.*',DB::raw('MAX(performance) AS personal_best')
    ->limit(100);
```

[Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#aggregates) says that we can do `max(personal_best)` but not sure how to use it with group by.

I'm afraid you can't avoid `DB::raw` in Query Builder but you can use `eloquent model` for the same, as answered by `Shaielndra Gupta`.

For that you can create model and relationship.

```
1. Create Model:
php artisan make:model Athelete
php artisan make:model Performance

2. Create relationship between Athelete and Perforamnce.

Update Athelete.php 

    /**
     * Get the performances for the Athelete post.
     */
    public function performances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Performance');
    }

3. Get data(didn't verify by myself)
$data = Athelete::with('performances',function ($query) use ($eventId){
    $query->max('performance')
    $query->where('event_id',$eventId)
    $query->orderBy('performance');
})->get();
```

Reference:

- [Laravel Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models)
- [Laravel Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: I know how to solve it with sql but I need that sql rewrite to laravel query builder. I'm sorry if I didnt give enought description.

Comment: so I converted to eloquent but still not able get results now I'm getting error
`mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`
any idea it will be probably something minor

Comment: Sorry dude, right now in office, will be able to check later.

Comment: @MarekBarta, can you please show your code for the same. Athlete model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below.

```
$sql1 = "(
         SELECT performance
         FROM performances
         WHERE athletes.id = performances.athlete_id AND performances.event_id = 1
         ORDER BY performance DESC
         LIMIT 0,1
     ) AS personal_best";

$sql2 = "SELECT athletes.*,$sql1          
FROM athletes
ORDER BY personal_best DESC
Limit 0, 100";

$result = DB::select($sql2);
```

Comment: This solution working for me let me know is that working for you or not.

Comment: I need to avoid Raw sql because local database is different from the production one. Thats why I want to use laravel query builde so I dont have to write the same query twice. Once for local and once for prduction

Comment: If local database is different then you have to access table via model.
So you can define table name as constant and use in RAW SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you can user Eloquent ORM like this

```
$data = Athelete::with('performances',function ($query) use ($eventId){
    $query->max('performance')
    $query->where('event_id',$eventId)
    $query->orderBy('performance');
})->get()
```

Comment: And may I ask how should I make the "Athelete" I'm new with this so sorry if its a trivial thing

Comment: Athlete Is your model represents the table athletes and inside the Athlete, model defines the relationship with performance table for more you can see https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent

Comment: Ok, I see now. But would you know how to do it without using Eloquent ORM only using laravel query builder?

Comment: Bro i am eloquent guy 